# ORACLE SQL to get MINUTE difference - 60 minute difference is showing as ZERO

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I am trying to get the minute difference between JOB_START_TIME '20-JUL-23 08.30.11.013206000 AM' and  JOB_END_TIME  '20-JUL-23 09.30.33.429231000 AM' - the expected result should show 60 minutes but  my query below is showing it as ZERO minutes:

```
    select 
        EXTRACT(MINUTE FROM 
            TO_TIMESTAMP(to_char(JOB_END_TIME,'DD-MON-YYYY HH:MI:SS'),'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS')
        -
            TO_TIMESTAMP(to_char(JOB_START_TIME,'DD-MON-YYYY HH:MI:SS'),'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS')
    ) AS MINUTE_DIFFERENCE


from jobs_table
```

Looks like the EXTRACT(MINUTE)  is converting 60 minutes to HH:MM  i.e., 1:00  and extracted the MINUTE part which returns 0.

How do I modify the above query to show 60 minutes and not 0 minutes?

Answer (score 0):

Don't use the timestamp datatype if you don't need fractions of a second - if these are dates, simply subtract them. If they are timestamps, cast them to dates:

Dates:

```
SELECT (JOB_END_TIME - JOB_START_TIME) * 1440 minute_difference
  FROM ...
```

Timestamps:

```
SELECT (CAST(JOB_END_TIME AS date) - CAST(JOB_START_TIME AS date)) * 1440 minute_difference
  FROM ...
```

When you subtract a date from a date, the result is a decimal number representing the number of days between them, which includes a fractional part. Multiplying that by the # of minutes in a day (1440) gives you minutes. If you wanted seconds, you would multiply by 86400. Date arithmetic is easier to work with than intervals which timestamp substraction produces.

Comment: i did try that but I am getting this format "+60 08:57:59.076000"  how do I extract the "60"  from that result?

Comment: It appears you have timestamps to start with, then. Updating my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to use `TO_TIMESTAMP` and `TO_CHAR`, just subtract the timestamps from each other.

If you want to get the hour difference then `EXTRACT` the `HOUR` component as well:

```sql
SELECT EXTRACT(HOUR   FROM JOB_END_TIME - JOB_START_TIME) AS HOUR_DIFFERENCE,
       EXTRACT(MINUTE FROM JOB_END_TIME - JOB_START_TIME) AS MINUTE_DIFFERENCE
```

If you just want the total minutes then multiple the hours by 60 and add to the minutes:

```sql
SELECT EXTRACT(HOUR FROM JOB_END_TIME - JOB_START_TIME) * 60
       + EXTRACT(MINUTE FROM JOB_END_TIME - JOB_START_TIME) AS MINUTE_DIFFERENCE
```